How to find number of integral solutions of the equation $\log _3(x+3 y)+x^2+3 y^2+4 x y-x-y=0$?
I am trying to find number of integral solutions of the equation $\log _3(x+3 y)+x^2+3 y^2+4 x y-x-y=0$ here $x$, $y$ are integer number $x\in [-2024, 2024]$ and $x + y >0$. I tried
NSolve[{Log[3, x + 3 y] + x^2 + 3 y^2 + 4  x  y - x - y == 0, 
  x + y > 0, -2024 <= x <= 2024}, {x, y}, Integers]

I can not get the result.

Try:Reduce[{Log[3, x + 3*y] + x^2 + 3*y^2 + 4*x*y - x - y == 0,     x + y > 0}, {x, y}, Integers] // FullSimplify ?

In view of the result of
Factor[x^2 + 3*y^2 + 4*x*y - x - y]


(x + y) (-1 + x + 3 y)

the equality -1 + x + 3y == 0 implies Log[3, x + 3  y]==0.
Therefore, all the solutions of
Reduce[-1 + x + 3 y == 0 && x + y > 0 && x >=-2024 && x <= 2024, {x, y}, Integers]


C[1] \[Element] Integers && 0 <= C[1] <= 674 && x == 1 + 3  C[1] &&  y == -C[1]

are integer solutions of the equation under consideration. The question about the existence of different from the above  solutions remains open.
Addition. If 3x +y > 1, then Log[3, x + 3  y] > 0, so Log[3, x + 3  y] + x^2 + 3  y^2 + 4   x   y - x - y > 0. If 3x +y < 1 && 3x + 1 >0, then Log[3, x + 3  y] <0, so Log[3, x + 3  y] + x^2 + 3  y^2 + 4   x   y - x - y <0 0. Therefore, there is no other integer solution than  C[1] \[Element] Integers && 0 <= C[1] <= 674 && x == 1 + 3  C[1] &&  y == -C[1] and the total number of the integer solutions of the equation under consideration   equals 675.

May be you can try FindInstance ?
f = Log[3, x + 3  y] + x^2 + 3  y^2 + 4   x   y - x - y
FindInstance[{f == 0, x + y > 0, -20 <= x <= 20}, {x, y}, Integers, 10]

gives
{{x->1,y->0},{x->4,y->-1},{x->7,y->-2},{x->10,y->-3},
    {x->13,y->-4},{x->16,y->-5},{x->19,y->-6}}

I change the domain of x to be smaller so it finishes faster as I noticed it was slow otherwise.
